# Cannot find 'Date' type when building Swagger generated API

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I am not sure if there is a built in Date type in Haskell or not, it is hard to tell and I can find no documentation.

Here are my import statements

```
import           Data.Aeson         (FromJSON (..), ToJSON (..), Value, genericParseJSON, genericToJSON)
import           Data.Aeson.Types   (Options (..), defaultOptions)
import           Data.Function      ((&))
import           Data.List          (stripPrefix)
import qualified Data.Map           as Map
import           Data.Maybe         (fromMaybe)
import           Data.Text          (Text)
import qualified Data.Text          as T
import           GHC.Generics       (Generic)
```

Here is the line in question

```
productionEntryProductionDate :: Date
```

And here is the error I get when trying to run `stack build`

`` Not in scope: type constructor or class `Date' ``

The code I have was from a Web API I generated from some Swagger 2.0 YAML.

I am fairly new to Haskell, so if you need more info please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date` is not a standard type in Haskell. You can either define your own or you can use `Day` from the [time library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.7). Either way you will need to define the Aeson instances for it yourself. The time library has a `parseTimeM` function which can do the work for you, but you still need the instance declarations.

**Correction**: it turns out that Aeson already has instances for both `Day` and `UTCTime` types.

Comment: Thanks, it was hard finding any resources on a "Date" type and now I know why.